# How to use a formula from a single cell, in multiple cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have some data and throughout the worksheet, I have a formula I'd like to use in a bunch of places.  The place to use my formula is not consistent, so I can't just re-do a formula in say `A1` and drag down to update the rest.

For example:
[image]

For simplicity, let's say in `G2`, and `G10`, I want just April + May's top row: so `G2` is `=D2+E2`.  Now, instead of having to remember I also have this formula in `G10`, I'd like to *reference* the formula in `G2`, and apply to `G10` (with the cell addresses updated relatively).

I've seen @teylyn's answer here: [Cell Formula to link to another cell and use that formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555184/cell-formula-to-link-to-another-cell-and-use-that-formula), and it *almost* does the trick.

I've created a named formula of `=D2+E2` and named it `myFormula`.  If I replace `G2` and `G10` with just `=myFormula`, it correctly evaluates to the sum of the two cells.  Yay!

However, The only thing is if I get more convoluted formulas than just `x+y`, it's a little annoying to use the Name Manager to edit/write the formula.

My goal: Put a formula in, say, `G1`, and then reference *that* formula.  So if `G1` has `=D1+E1&" is the sum!"`, `G2` and `G10` see it as `=D2+E2...` and `=D10+E10...`?  (My actual formula is more than just `x+y`, e.g. `=text(E2,"$* #,###")&" is the total for "&E1...`)

(I'm hoping for a non-VBA answer, so I can apply the answer and share with folks, without worrying about XLSM or addins they may not have.)

Comment: `=IF((NOT(ISNUMBER(E1:E1000))*(E1:E1000<>""),E2:E1001+D2:D1001,"")`?  In G2 and it should spill

Comment: Have you tried the following Excel Add-in: [Advanced Formula Environment](https://github.com/microsoft/advanced-formula-environment) this may solve the problem of dealing with the Name Manager.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Yeah, seems like that would work specifically for `x+y`.  My real formula is pretty convoluted, e.g. `=text(E2,"$* #,###")&" is the total amount for "&E1...`.

Comment: @DavidLeal - Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately I can't use any external add-ins.

Comment: This is kind of what LAMBDAs are for? Using the formula `=D1+E1` in the Name manager will confine you to maintaining the relative positions of the formula and your arguments. LAMBDA lets you just define two parameters, which can be taken from anywhere. What some people do is test the LAMBDA in a spreadsheet cell eg `=LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)(D1,E1)` first, and then when it is working to your satisfaction, define a Name by cutting & pasting the formula without the `(D1,E1)` part. That may be a half-way house for you: I don't think Excel is set up for the kind of meta-functions you describe.

Comment: @BruceWayne you would just replace the E2 and E1 with their ranges or use LET(): `=LET(d,D1:XLOOKUP("*",D:D,D:D,,2,-1),e,E1:XLOOKUP("*",D:D,E:E,,2,-1),ttle,drop(e,-1),dte,DROP(e,1),dtd,DROP(d,1),IF((NOT(ISNUMBER(ttle)))*(ttle<>""),dte+dtd,""))`  Then you would just replace `dte+dtd` with your formula using `dte` in place of `E2` and `dtd` in place of `D2`

Comment: Is it correct that from the question you'd like to just write a formula once? Then refer to this formula and get the relative positions of the ranges referenced in the original formula? If so, why don't you just create a named function 'Z' for example. Refer to `=TEXT(INDEX(E:E,ROW()),"$* #,###")&" is the total for "&E$1)`. Offcourse this is a simple example, but the idea is to use the `INDEX(...,ROW())` syntax to now be able to enter `=Z` in any of your cells down column `E:E`. However, I do agree with @DS_London, you might want to start looking into `LAMBDA()` using parameters.

Comment: People who don't like editing defined Names generally aren't familiar with [cell modes](https://www.excel-first.com/excel-cell-modes/) - once you remember to press F2 it becomes much easier, and it's always more efficient to edit a formula in one place (and have it propagate everywhere it's used) than to have to edit it in every single cell where it's used.

Comment: @JvdV - Yes - I'd like to write the formula once.  Say in cell `D1` I have `=A1+B1&" is the total"`.  Then, if I want to use that formula, somehow refer to that cell.  So if in `D10` I put `=[SOME REFERENCE?]` it resolves `=A10+B10&" is the total"` --> `100 is the total` (or whatever the math ends up doing).  I'll have to look into `LAMBDA`

Comment: If you copy cell `D1` (Ctrl+c) and paste in `D10` (ctrl-v) the cell references shift the same number of rows and since the column isn't shifted, that remains unchanged. Isn't that what you mean?

Comment: DS_London is right that this is what LAMBDAS were introduced for. But that doesn't mean that they are a good idea. I think you are applying a programmer mindset to Excel formulae, when they actually work best with a different mindset. If you step back and explain your top-level objective there may be something much simpler that is possible.